# Connecting C++ program with Java API

Tags: javascript, java, c++, api, encryption

I have a C++ AES alogirthm program, which I am using to encrypt text files, that are present on the same machine. 
Now I am increasing its functionality by uploading new files on that machine from different machines, by making use of a web app.

My web app is made of java, which will be linked to the server machine through an API (which is also built on java). 
When a user hits the upload button (present on web app), the API is called, and it will upload the file, on the server machine. 
The work is going smooth till this point as I have successfully received file on server machine from different machine (present on same LAN for now).

However, now I am stuck. I want my C++ program to know somehow, automatically, that a new file has arrived on the machine, take it from there and encrypt it. But how can that be done?

Up till my understanding I thought maybe JavaScript could be used, but I don't really know how that would work.

Kindly let me know if I need to provide any more details. Any guidance would be really appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: In c++ you can monitor a directory for new files appearing. On Linux you have inotify on Windows there is something.

Comment: I'm assuming that there's some type of file upload event handler in the Java application that you use to upload the files, which also saves them on the server.  If that's the case then you just need to execute the C++ application after that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me - your Java program downloads the file and puts it into some known location? so why don't you just create JNI wrapper (a jar lib) for your c++ application and then, after success download, you just tell your lib /path/to/file and encrypt it?

Maybe you can also encrypt the byte stream you receiving and write already encrypted bytes to disk?

Answer (score -1):

This might help you, if I understood you correctly:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is a working example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIR_PATH L"C:\\temp\\files"

void encrypt(WCHAR* fileName);
OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
union {
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION i;
    char d[sizeof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)+MAX_PATH];
} fni;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hDirectory;
    BOOL res;
    DWORD bytesReturned;

    // Create handle for the directory
    hDirectory =  CreateFileW(DIR_PATH, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
    overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(0,0,0,0);

    // Monitor as long as running
    while (1)
    {
        res = ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDirectory,(LPVOID)&fni,sizeof(fni),FALSE,FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE,
                                                                &bytesReturned,&overlapped,NULL);
        // Error checking
        if ( res == 0)
        {
            printf("error: %d\n",GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        // check if a new file has been created in the directory
        GetOverlappedResult(hDirectory,&overlapped,&bytesReturned,TRUE);
        if (fni.i.Action != 0)
            encrypt(fni.i.FileName);
    }
}

//This is the encryption function
void encrypt(WCHAR* fileName)
{
    wprintf(L"Encrypting code here!\nFileName=%ls\n",fileName);
}
```

Just replace the DIR_PATH and edit the encrypt function

(My first answer here btw ^^)

Comment: This is very useful indeed. Thanks a bunch! Will comment here again, if I need any further understanding of this concept. But this surely helped me a lot! Cheers!

Comment: my code is in c++, will it work with that? Considering its C right?